# Integrate Reactjs with Spring-mvc (With Gradle)

Tags: reactjs, spring-mvc, gradle

Can anyone here help me with an issue? I'm trying to integrate Reactjs with Spring-mvc where I'm using Gradle as the build. I've looked at opinions from different people but all the answers I got used Maven instead of Gradle. I really need help

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be specific with your problem over here and mention the exact issue or difficulties you are coming across while integration. Also Gradle or Maven do not make a diffference if you know how to set them up. Infact gradle is more beneficial in my knowledge.